# Set value in Firestore based on other document values

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a set of items in Firestore, and I want to change a property in a document when a criteria is met in Firestore.

- Rooms collection

  - Room document

    - ...properties
    - all_answered property
  - Users collection

    - guid User doc

      - answered property
    - guid User doc

      - answered property

When every user in the users collection has the answered property as true, I want to set the "all_answered" property to true as well in the Room document. These User docs will be on different devices, obviously. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few common approaches here, and some complications. For easier parsing I'll put them in a list.

- "All answered" is a dynamic value, i.e. when a new user joins the system the value should become false again. For this reason I recommend keeping a counter for the number of users that have answered, and for the total number of users. If the two values are the same, all people have answered.
- With that, you can then update the `answeredCount` property whenever any user updates their `answered` property value. Doing this in a transaction or batched write to ensure it's atomic.
- Then when you need to know if all users have answered, you read the user count in your code, and then run a query where you compare `answeredCount` with the value you just read.

An alternative approach, closer to what you suggest already in your question:

- You could also periodically run a query that counts the number of users  and the number of users that answered (both with the new [COUNT() feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries)), and sets the flag field based on these counts).

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!